Looking for a function equivalent to "resizeRowToIndex" for QTableView
I am working with a QTableView, and I'd like for the row to change its height to accommodate the content of the selected index.
The function resizeRowToContents is not really what I am looking for. If I click on a cell [A] that doesn't need to change its height to display everything but a cell [B] in the row needs to, the row will increase its height to accommodate [B].
Using sizeHintForRow would result in the same behaviour as using resizeRowToContents
The function sizeHintForIndex doesn't return the correct value for some reason.
In the C++ source of Qt there is a private function heightHintForIndex that would be exactly what I need  (because it's used by resizeRowToContents).
Is there a function that I am missing, or does anyone know a way to do it?
I am using my own QStyledItemDelegate for those cells.

You've already found the function, which is relatively small. Can't you just study what it does and reproduce it?

@musicamante I tried. But the function 'heightHintForIndex' uses a private function 'editorForIndex' which uses a class 'QIndexEditorHash' I can't use. Or I don't know how to use. What I understand is I need to get the editor of the index and get the hintSize, but what I tried doesn't work. I probably don't understand well enough the way the delegate/editor stuff work...

If you're not in editing mode, there's no editor at all, so you can skip that part. Alternatively, just use indexWidget(), which would have the same result (since it returns the result of the internal call to editorForIndex()).

@musicamante Unfortunately indexWidget returns NoneType when I click on a cell.

But are you in editing mode? Otherwise there's no editor, therefore there is nothing to return.

@musicamante I am not. I am just clicking on a cell. My goal is to increase the size of the row to adapt to the content of the clicked cell. A bit like using resizeRowToContents but only for the clicked cell. I am wondering how Qt calculates the height of the row when I call resizeRowToContents.

That's the point: if there is no editor, you don't need that part of the function to begin with, do you? Just implement what follows that.

Alright, I've done it. I was already trying to implement the rest of the function, but I think I didn't understand well enough the QStyleOptionViewItem.

Basically, I wrote the function heightHintForIndex in Python.
def on_selection_changed(self, selected: QModelIndex , deselected: QModelIndex):
    
    self.setRowHeight(deselected.row(), 1)
    editor = self.indexWidget(selected)
    hint = 0
    if (editor is not None) and (self.isPersistentEditorOpen(selected)):
        hint = max(hint, editor.sizeHint().height())
        min_ = editor.minimumSize().height()
        max_ = editor.maximumSize().height()
        hint = max(min_, min(max_, hint))
        
    option = QStyleOptionViewItem()
    self.initViewItemOption(option)
    option.rect.setY(self.rowViewportPosition(selected.row()))
    height = self.rowHeight(selected.row())
    if height == 0:
        height = 1
    option.rect.setHeight(self.rowHeight(selected.row()))
    option.rect.setX(self.columnViewportPosition(selected.column()))
    option.rect.setWidth(self.columnWidth(selected.column()))

    if self.showGrid():
        option.rect.setWidth(option.rect.width() - 1)

    new_height = max(hint, self.itemDelegateForIndex(selected).sizeHint(option, selected).height())

    self.setRowHeight(selected.row(), new_height)

